# Как распарсить json в c#?

Tags: c#, json

Всем доброго дня.
Я только начинаю программировать и многого не понимаю, поэтому отнеситесь с пониманием. Прошу помощи, помогите распарсить json. Вот такой ответ приходит с сервера:

```
{"lastUpdateId":390449153,"bids":[["0.03714000","2.24400000",[]],["0.03713900","3.00000000",[]],["0.03713800","0.61900000",[]],["0.03713700","11.00000000",[]],["0.03712700","2.85600000",[]],["0.03712500","10.00000000",[]],["0.03712400","1.00000000",[]],["0.03711900","0.04100000",[]],["0.03711200","1.54900000",[]],["0.03711100","4.03900000",[]]],"asks":[["0.03714800","6.29300000",[]],["0.03714900","0.24900000",[]],["0.03715100","0.24900000",[]],["0.03715900","0.56500000",[]],["0.03716500","67.20000000",[]],["0.03716700","9.73500000",[]],["0.03716900","6.67600000",[]],["0.03717200","13.67400000",[]],["0.03717500","0.02700000",[]],["0.03717700","0.91600000",[]]]}
```

Нужно с каждого массива взять два значения, до запятой и после. 
Желательно по подробней, может с примерами.

Comment: `Я только начинаю программировать и многого не понимаю` - мой вам совет, научитесь искать информацию и разбираться в ней сами, не ленитесь! Даже на RuSO есть уйма ответов на эту тему, достаточно просто написать в поиске грамотный запрос. А с таким подходом... через месяц-другой вы попросту забьете на это дело. Не ленитесь!!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прав. На сайте полно ответов по типу _"как распарсить вот такой json"_ и другое. Достаточно в поиск вбить **"json c#"** и посмотреть нужную вам ситуацию. Попробуйте что ни будь сами, почитайте на сайтах про то как с этим работать. Идите в сторону `Newtonsoft.Json`. Желаю удачи!